# Is there any weighted graph which smallest eigenvalue of its adjacency matrix is greater than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any weighted or unweighted graph which smallest eigenvalue of its adjacency matrix is greater than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph has no loops, then the answer is "no" since the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the adjacency matrix which is zero. Hence there must be at least one eigenvalues that is $\leq 0$.

If the graph has loops, then yes: just take a single vertex with two loops.